# Correct way to revert back to originating server?

Tags: asterisk

I have two servers on the same network.
SIP is setup with canreinvite=yes

I call Server 2 from server 1 with DIAL() cmd

**What is the correct way to revert back to server 1 after I am complete with the call on server 2 without dropping the channel?** (I still want the channel active to offer the user specific options back on server 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use "g" option of Dial command like this:

```
exten => _X.,n,Dial(SIP/mytrunk/${EXTEN},,g)
```

After Dial command it will continue to run next Dialplan command of Server 1. More details you can find here:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Dial